# I am not able to design a beautiful border in Menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to add a border with a cut. And I wrote code of it, I did all the things but not able to make a cut in border ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRFuz.jpg)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.box{
background-color:#fff;
border:none;
color:#000;
font-size:30px;
position:relative;
margin:22px;
}

.box::before {
content:'';
width:100%;
height:130%;
top:-10px;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:-20px;
position:absolute;
border: 3px solid #36b4c2;
border-width:3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="box" > Menu </button><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Am I on wrong track. Is there any other tag to add a border with a cut.

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index: -1; in :before selector

Comment: But When I added it to my website menu with using z-index, it worked but that backed line still visible (link - https://imgur.com/a/BnNAUAc), how to remove that line?

Comment: make sure the background color exists @Pramod